# Number of ways in which the books may be arranged on the shelf, if the volumes of each set are together and in their due order is

Tags: combinatorics

> Prove that if a shelf contains $20$ different books, of which $4$ are in single volume and the others form sets of $8$, $5$ and $3$ volumes, respectively.  Number of ways in which the books may be arranged on the shelf, if the volumes of each set are together and in their due order is $8!$.

---

I took the books with multi-volumes as single units,so there are $7$ units, and I got the answer as $7!$, not $8!$ as demanded.  Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I don't see anything wrong.  It is probably a typo in the book.